# Traffic lights with 555 and 4017 (only red LED lights up)

Tags: 555

I have been trying to simulate a traffic light circuit (UK version) in Tinkercad. However, only the red LED lights up. How can I resolve the issue?

The schematic I used:
[image]

Scheme (mine):
[image]

If only the red LED lights up it's probably because of the delay, or the 555 not oscillating properly.

Build a proper 555 astable circuit and attach an LED to pin 3 to check if the oscillator is OK (LED should blink).

Make sure all connections are correct. Wiper of pot should be connected to either of the other terminals on pot.

Comment: Attach a resistor and LED to the output (pin 3) of the 555. Use this as a probe to check if you're sending pulses to the 4017.

Comment: You have asked similar questions in the past, what was the resolution to those questions?

Comment: I'm curious, what makes this a "uk version"?

Comment: it can display red and yellow together.

Comment: @Hearth, in the UK the yellow (amber actually) turns on with the red for a couple of seconds before switching to green. It should result in a quicker take-off. Ireland is next door and in the republic we don't but Northern Ireland (part of UK) does.

Comment: check that the 555 is making pulses , checkj that the 4017 is connected to +9 and 0V everywhere it should be, check the voltage on pin 15

Comment: The schematic you used has an obvious problem around pin 5 of the 555. Compare with other "555 astable" circuits. Also, divide and conquer : get the 555 working first (see Transistor's comment) before moving on to the rest.

Comment: 555 will run OK with pin 5 unconnected, it looses supply ripple immunity, but that shouldn't  hinder operation.

Comment: ye there is pulse for 555 ic (attached a blue led and its blinking) . Also for some reason the 4017 ic will blow if the supply voltage is over 7v

Comment: Check the data sheet for the 74HC4017.  It's only meant to go up to 7V max.  9V will probably blow it.

Comment: what Simon says is probably it. Turn the voltage down to 5V.   if you want to use 9V you need CD4017 instead of 74HC4017

Comment: still only lights up red. Will there be a diff if i use a 74hc4017 instead of a cd4017

Comment: nvm i solved just needed to wait 10 seconds for circuit to continue . My impatience was the problem , sry for the trouble . Thx for the help anyways!

Comment: It may be more instructive to build a [Johnson counter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter#Johnson_counter) from (quad: 74175) D-type flip-flops with complementary outputs and see how to decode a signal with just *any* single part of the cycle active with just a single two-input gate.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wire from the potentiometer connected to the wrong end of the 100k resistor. It needs to be connected to pin 7 of the 555.

You also appear to have an extra wire that shorts pins 2 and 6 of the 555 directly to the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 wiring errors for function  and too many long jumpers for quality of logic in the layout.

1. The 330 ohm R has 2 wiring errors.

Can you correct these?  The G,Y LEDS have no current limit and may be burnt out. The LEDs are all common cathode to one shared 330 R to gnd.

Making the layout look like the schematic will help you in future or trace the schematic with a coloured pen to verify every trace.

Comment: `G,Y LEDS have no current limit` according to the schematic. They do have a 330 Ω resistor in the TinkerCAD image.