# I'm looking for a traffic light circuit which includes a pedestrian crossing using a 555 timer IC

Tags: 555

I'm looking for a basic traffic light circuit to make a toy crossing.

- There will be 1 traffic light using the typical lighting sequence.
- A button for the pedestrian to request crossing
- red/green crossing lights (walk/don't walk) which are activated
- A buzzer to alert when it is safe to cross

I don't want to use any microcontrollers, just simple electrical components.

Googling indicates a 555IC or maybe two are required, but I'm yet to find a diagram which suits my needs. The closest I've found is [here](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/a42549/picaxe-traffic-light-with-pedestrian-crossing/) but that uses a microcontroller. I have seen [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579675/traffic-lights-with-555-and-4017-only-red-led-light-up-solution) which uses a 555.

This will be a birthday present for my nephew, so all help or pointers are appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT
To answer the logic question, this is the sequencing I'd like to create:

There is the traffic light sequence, this is interrupted if the push button is activated and the sequence is at the red light only.

```
TR = Red traffic light
TA = Amber traffic light
TG = Green traffic light

PR = Red pedestrian light
PG = Green pedestrian light

Turn on
# traffic light sequence
TR on, (TA, TG off) State A
Wait n seconds
TR, TA on, (TG off) State B
Wait n seconds
TG on, (TR, TA off) State C
Wait n seconds
TA on, (TR, TG off) State D
Wait n seconds
TR on, (TA, TG off) State E

IF Pedestrian button == pushed:
  IF TR on (and TA not on, State A):
    PG on (PR off)
    Wait n seconds
    PG flash
    Wait n seconds
    PG off, PR on
  ELSE:
    wait
```

Comment: Why are you dismissing microcontrollers? They'd be by far the simplest *and* most flexible solution.

Comment: I want it to be simple, yes I can code, but for this one I want a non-programmed solution.

Comment: 'Educational' is a valid reason :) To implement the logic (e.g. traffic lights goes yellow then red, then pedestrian light goes green, etc.) you will need quite a few discrete logic chips. Start by defining all the states and the tranistions between them (maybe draw a state machine diagram). Once you have formalized the logic, come back when you need help with mapping it to a circuit. Same if you need help debouncing the button or driving the buzzer.

Comment: by the way, the moment you've defined the logic, you'll realize you've built a *finite state machine*, so that's the technical term I'd look up here. (by the way, if you build some kind of sequencer that checks conditions from some stored list and can switch between these states, that's a small custom CPU!)

Comment: and by the way, the 555 is ... ok, yeah, you can use that, but why define that so early? Just because a lot of students have googled the same and then copied the approach of someone from the 1970s? Your main problem lies in logic, so you could just as well use the logic ICs you have, anyway, to form an oscillator, and use a counter to time things. Getting rid of the rather cumbersome and complicated 555. Maybe the 555 is a nice solution to generate the clock? Why not. But it feels very anti-engineering to define the part you use before having approached a solution.

Comment: Define "simple components". Gates? Counters? Shift registers? We need to know where your boundary lies.

Comment: Logic added to the OP, @Finbarr, I'm not sure what is best, I'm familiar with 555IC, transistors, resistors, capacitors etc. This is what I refer to as 'simple components', perhaps generic or basic components is a better way to put it, not microcontrollers.

Comment: Start with the state transition diagram for this problem.  If you're not familiar with such artifacts, you might do a bit of research first.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, on *But it feels very anti-engineering to define the part you use before having approached a solution* It's a pretty common engineering thing to do that, though. I've found there's much more to weigh up when selecting COTS parts circuitry, CPLDs/FPGAs or MCUs than just the circuit itself. The hefty MCU overhead costs almost always gets disregarded on this site by MCU advocates. Nearly all part selections are commercial first, electronic second, I've seen that in all designs I've worked on. (cont'd)

Comment: @MarcusMüller (cont'd) Here, there's obviously no dev costs but may well be a teaching example circuit so the 'easiest' one ain't the goal. Or the OP just wants to enjoy exploring the discrete approach, for their own reasons. They were up-front about their direction. The COTS parts approach is by far the best teaching version. The worst thing you can do to creative people to get them to be creative is to impose no limits, which is essentially what the MCU option does. Make it difficult and the mind has to explore, struggle, stretch, get ingenious. I learnt and still learn far more that way :-)

Comment: @TonyM impossible to argue with the fact that economic aspects typically drive most things! My criticism did not aim at the discrete-solution here (at all!) but at trying to work from one of many parts that make up the system - and at that, with one with lesser import (imho). Of course you're right, in practical development processes you need to settle on a central component relatively early – but the MCU/FPGA/application processor/discrete logic/ASIC design choice typically done on prior experience or guidance, or a very quick capability K.O. criterion check.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little mad given that you've almost written the microcontroller code, however ...

[image]

*Figure 1. A starting point. Image source: [Electrical Technology](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2014/10/traffic-light-control-electronic-project.html).*

The 4017 is a Johnson ring counter. It has ten outputs which are switched on sequentially by the clock signal on pin 14. In this example the red is on for one clock cycle, the yellow for two and the green for four.

You'll need to modify this to get the required number of steps and resolution you require. There are many articles on the 4017 freely available on the web. Some will show you how to daisy-chain multiple chips to make a longer sequence.

Comment: But it's not a great design given the lack of series resistor for the green LED.

Comment: *This seems a little mad* Only if using an MCU meets the project requirements (rather than just makes the smallest circuit), which it may well not. Your green one'll get hot :-)